# Looking for a SAAS with step-by-step test cases + email alert on success + github issue opening on failure

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, git

Anyone knows such a service?

Want it to be as simple as possible and use it mainly for running sanity checks on every version.

I want to define a test case (hopefully divided to sections) and be able to run it multiple times by checking a checkbox for every passing step and if a step fails - write some text and add a print-screen which will open a GitHub issue (authentication can be with OAuth of GitHub security tokens).

This just sounds like something that must be there somewhere but I'm not from the QA world so would love to get your recommendations.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:manual-testing]?

Comment: @Adelin - because I'm looking for a service that will help me run manual tests with the features I've described. Do you know any?

Comment: If you would've said automation I would've suggested something like [SRF](https://software.microfocus.com/ru-ru/products/functional-testing-as-a-service/overview) but for manual...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I understood you are in need of test case management tool where you can execute the manual test cases on every sanity checks and if the test case fails it has to be logged in GitHub where your developer has access to open the issue and fix it.

There are so many test case management tool in the market like Test collab, QA Touch, Test lodge, Test Rail with GIT hub integration

Answer (score 0):

My favorite suite of tools for test management is:

- Jira.  For the ticket board
- Confluence.  For knowledge management
- Github.  For code and Code Review processes
- CircleCI.  For running tests in the cloud

The above tools integrate well together

The only piece I don't know is about opening a ticket automatically.  To be honest I don't feel that would be that useful to me because:

- UI tests are often have intermittent errors.  Getting bug tickets for each may be over-whelming
- Bug tickets frequently need context and human comments in order to make sense.
- Auto generated tickets still need to be reviewed for priority before being worked on
- Auto generated tickets could easily create many duplicates to be managed and closed